# how to bind dataviewmodel in module using prism wpf mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, prism-4

My Prisam Application 'Initializing modules' successFuly module view call by view Module fill.
But loding view not set detacontex view module.To add modul,I can used this code:

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
            ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleR1Customer.ViewModule.CustomerViewModules));
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleR2Order.ViewModule.OrderViewModules));
        }
```

how to solved this problem?
please Help me.

Comment: Your question still a little bit unclear though, could you give us more detail ?

Comment: in xaml file view model not load.how to sate detacontex using view model?

Comment: According to your comment I changed my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all what you need.
- Create a general interfaces `IViewModel` `IView` and  and special interface to that view (`ITiersView`). By implementing your special interface to your View view code behind should look like below :

```
     public interface IViewModel
{
}

public interface IView
{
    IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public interface ITiersView : IView
{
}

    //My View
    public partial class Tiers : UserControl , ITiersView
    {
        public Tiers(ITiersViewModel tiersViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = tiersViewModel;
        }

        public SmartStock.Infrastructure.IViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return (ITiersViewModel)DataContext;
            }
            set
            {
                DataContext = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

To make this loads you need to use [Unity container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx) in your modulinit class like this :

```
        _container.RegisterType<ITiersView, Tiers>();
        _container.RegisterType<ITiersViewModel, TiersViewModel>();
        IRegion Content = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ContentRegion];
        var TiersView = _container.Resolve<ITiersView>();
        RibbonRegion.Add(TiersView);
```